# Getting paste to output column-wise when input is from a pipe

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program that processes a number of data files in a for loop in bash. At the moment I need to output each loop step to a separate file and then process all those files again at the end in order to tabulate them. I would like to avoid the step of going via files to do this, and use the basic shell commands to do so. It seems like that should be possible, but I've hit a brick wall. The following is an example that illustrates the rough procedure:

```
#create some example data
seq 1 100 > results-all
split -l 10 -d -a 1 results-all results-
#process the data
for RESULT in `seq 0 9`; do tail -n-5 results-$RESULT > results-clean-$RESULT; done; paste results-clean-{0..9}
```

Please bear in mind that this is an example, in reality I'm doing a lot more processing on those input files so an oversimplified solution with that step moved elsewhere / removed somehow is unlikely to work in practice (this is *just* an example). When I try to change this code to remove the intermediate step of going via files, I lose the ability to get paste to format my input into columns. Thus:

```
for RESULT in `seq 0 9`; do tail -n-5 results-$RESULT; done | paste - - - - - - - - - -
```

Now the output is row-wise rather than column-wise. I could transpose this data, but there doesn't appear to be a shell tool to do that. I can write code to do a transpose on this (or copy an example from Stack Overflow to do that), but it seems like there should be a way to do this without resorting to that.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can play with the `-s` option of `paste`?

Er... no, won't work. We have the `column` utility:

```
for RESULT in `seq 0 9`; do tail -n-5 results-$RESULT; done | column -c100
```

But funny enough, the number or columns output is controlled by current the width of the terminal! :-/

#### EDIT

`column -c100` works for me to produce the desired output, but I guess it also depends on the length of the standard tabulation on your system...

#### EDIT2

Ok, so what the OP wants is a behaviour of `column` by which one cat tell it the height of the output matrix in number of rows, whatever the size of the terminal. I added a `-h numrows` option to `column`, the original `column` coming from the BDSutils (packet **bsdmainutils** on my Debian).

Please find [my modified version there](http://codeshare.io/3hIMY). Compile simply with:

```
cc -o column column.c
```

And then run:

```
for RESULT in `seq 0 9`; do tail -n-5 results-$RESULT; done | /path/to/new/column -h5
```

To get columns of height 5. This option is compatible with the `-x` flag that fills your matrix in the other direction (i.e. by rows).

Comment: paste -s results-clean-{0..9} will do a similar thing to the above. And when invoked on stdinput it just consumes the whole stream in one line.

Comment: I tried column with various parameters (I think pretty much every permutation...), but couldn't get it to do this. Perhaps I missed something? Also, for me, the "-c" param to control the display columns just makes it one column whatever I set it to (unless I don't set it, in which case the output is something like the width of the display as you say).

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use intermediate files, using `paste` is just not the right solution, because then stdinput is just a big "column". You have to use the `column` utility, see my last edit.

Comment: @Dunk about last comment: the integer you give as parameter to the -c option is a width expressed in number of chars, not in number of columns.

Comment: That does appear to work, though of course it's very sensitive to the data's width, which isn't an easy thing to control :-/. Even displaying all the data, for instance, kills it: for RESULT in `seq 0 9`; do cat results-$RESULT; done | column -c 100

Comment: Yes, then `-c 95`! ;) Joking, of course. But you could give to this option a value calculated beforehand as a bash variable: `... | column -c ${mywidth}`

Comment: And you have some play in that, because it's not so sensitive: for instance the values in the range from 85 to 95 seem to work well on the example you give in your last comment.

Comment: The trouble is that it's really not very general at all. In my case, the numbers are floating point and may be clipped here and there to various different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here would  be to use read and multiple file descriptors for the input.

**EDIT:** I have figured out a way to automate the file descriptor assignment: In a exec they are kept.

```
for FDNR in `seq 0 9`; do eval exec "{fd$FDNR}<results-$FDNR"; done
while read -u $fd0 FILELINE ; do 
   echo -n $FILELINE
   for FDNR in `seq 1 9`; do 
       otherfd=fd$FDNR
       read -u ${!otherfd} FILELINE; 
       echo -n -e \\t$FILELINE
   done 
   echo
done 
for FDNR in `seq 0 9`; do eval exec "{fd$FDNR}<&-"; done
```

The general idea is you assign each of your inputs to an own file descriptor, and you read in a loop from the different file descriptors, one line of each file and put it out (atm seperated by a tab). After you put out one line of the file, you make an empty echo to go the next line (before suppressed with -n).

Comment: I'm easier just writing a matrix-transpose if I'm going to code something. It it just seems like this should be solvable *without* the need to resort to a bespoke script.

Comment: `column` is the right tool, but unfortunately it has been written with a terminal-centric viewpoint, with the idea of trying to give the best column output for the given terminal. I'm just adding to it the relevant option and will post new answer here in a couple of minutes...